# Keeping variables in a class after refresh PHP

Tags: php

i come here with a question:
I have a `class User` created in a php file, this class is included in 2 main files, it's there any chance to save values in that file? I mean, in the moment when i refresh the page, my variables saved in class are gone, and i want to save them without using `$_SESSION`.
So, i'm so interested to know if there's a solution, or i just need to use the statement `$_SESSION` to refresh my variables everytime?

```
public function getVariables($email){
        $stmt = $this->DB->Connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $this->type WHERE email=:email",array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        $this->id = $result[0];
        $this->fname = $result[1];
        $this->lname = $result[2];
        $this->name = $this->lname." ".$this->fname;
        $this->CNP = $result[3];
        $this->birthday = $result[4];
        $this->email = $result[5];
        $this->university = $result[6];
        $this->faculty = $result[7];
        $this->password = $result[8];
        $this->gender = $result[9];
        $this->imgURL = $result[10];
        $this->darkmode = $result[12];
        $this->reset_code = $result[13];
        $this->reset_active = $result[14];
        $this->activationCode = $result[15];
        $this->activeDate = $result[16];
        $this->loginIP = $result[17];
        $this->loginIPS = $result[18];
        $this->auth = $result[19];
        $this->activated = $result[20];
    }
```

Comment: You could either: use cookies, use files, or use a database.

Comment: that's what i mean, i don't want to use either of those things

Comment: @AlphaMirage and how to use files for this? Or you mean to write the data in a file, and after a refresh to load the data?

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu How long should the values be "saved" somewhere? Why do you not want to use sessions (assuming it is actual session data)? What is the problem in saving the values in a database? What is the problem in general you have with your approach/code?

Comment: w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a stateless language. So unless you store the data in session, DB, file, or any other external resource, it's not achieveable to keep the values after reload.

> *So, i'm so interested to know if there's a solution, or i just need to use the statement $_SESSION to refresh my variables everytime?*

You'll need to use `$_SESSION` or another external resource.